# Node: Consume API Call and Pass to another API Call

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, promise

Sorry if this has been asking already but I cannot seem to find a straight answer.

I need to post data to one API endpoint that returns a token. I then need to use that token in a header to make a separate GET request to another endpoint to return the data I want.

The tokens are only good for a few minutes so if the GET endpoint responds token invalid it will send another POST request to get a new token and start the process all over.

I have been trying multiple async methods, promises, etc without luck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add the relevant pieces of your code. Show us what you tried so far using async or promises. Probably you are close. The general idea to use a promise to chain those api calls, goes in the right direction. And also you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it really helps

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually:

```
await apiCall2(
  await apiCall1()
);
```